# How do I render and replace changes to a specific tag in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an auction section in my React app, but can't quite get it to work. I would like for the page to render the added auction amount to the original  with the starting bid. I've tried doing this without state and have gone through various iterations and haven't gotten to work.

Below you'll find the code of my most recent code iteration from my Auction component:

```
import React from "react"
import AuctionItems from "../AuctionItems"

class Auction extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            bid: 0
        }
        this.addHundred = this.addHundred.bind(this)
    }

    addHundred() {
        this.setState((state) => {
            console.log ({bid: state.bid + 100})
        })
    }

    render() {

        const items = AuctionItems.map(item => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h4>{item.name}</h4>
                    <h4>${item.starting_bid}</h4>
                    <button onClick={this.addHundred}>Bid $100</button>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Auction</h1>
                {items}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Auction
```

Comment: I assume you want to independently bid for each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state needs to be a bit more complex because you want to track bids for each item. The following uses a `bids` piece of your state that stores each item's bid keyed by the item name.

```
import React from "react"
import AuctionItems from "../AuctionItems"

class Auction extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            bids: {}
        }
        this.addHundred = this.addHundred.bind(this)
    }

    addHundred(item) {
        this.setState((state) => ({
            bids: {
                ...state.bids,
                [item.name]: (state.bids[item.name] || 0) + 100
            }
        }));
    }

    render() {

        const items = AuctionItems.map(item => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h4>{item.name}</h4>
                    <h4>
                        ${item.starting_bid + (this.state.bids[item.name] || 0)}
                    </h4>
                    <button onClick={() => this.addHundred(item)}>
                      Bid $100
                    </button>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Auction</h1>
                {items}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Auction
```